# How to send an array list using google's volley in android?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, arrays

> I have an Array List of type CategoryInfo. I want to know how I can
>   send this arraylist using the volley library in android.I tried
>   converting the array list into a array list of strings then into an
>   array and then finally created a long string and then sent it using
>   volley.
>
> But I feel there has to be a better solution than this? This is what I
>   have tried so far but I would like to send the data in a better format
>   such that it is easier for me to insert it into my mysql db.

```
 ArrayList<CategoryInfo> orderArray =dbHandler.getOrderList();

                ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<orderArray.size();i++)
                {
                    CategoryInfo list = orderArray.get(i);
                    String serviceItemId = list.getServiceItemId();
                    String serName = list.getServiceName();
                    String cat_name = list.getCategoryName();
                    String item_name = list.getServiceItemName();
                    int item_rate = list.getServiceItemRate();
                    int item_qty = list.getQuantity();
                    int item_total = list.getItemTotal();
                    arrayList.add(serName);
                    arrayList.add(cat_name);
                    arrayList.add(item_name);
                    arrayList.add(String.valueOf(item_rate));
                    arrayList.add(String.valueOf(item_qty));
                    arrayList.add(String.valueOf(item_total));

                    Log.d("OrderArray",serviceItemId+" "+serName+" "+cat_name+" "+item_name+" "+String.valueOf(item_rate)+" "+String.valueOf(item_qty)+" "+String.valueOf(item_total));
                }

                /*ArrayList to Array Conversion */
                String array[] = new String[arrayList.size()];
                for(int j =0;j<arrayList.size();j++){
                    array[j] = arrayList.get(j);
                }

                String orders = Arrays.toString(array);
                String ord = orders.replaceAll("\\[","");
                ord = ord.replaceAll("\\]","");
                Log.d("orders",ord);

                set_orderinfo(ord);//This method contains my volley code.
```

I am new to programming any help or suggestion is most welcome.Thank you.

Comment: "I want to know how I can send this arraylist using the volley library in android" -- the more important question is: what is your server expecting in terms of a format for this request? For example, if the server is expecting JSON, there are many JSON APIs available for Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you give a example.Thank you.

Comment: Give an example of *what*? A Web server? You are sending a Volley request to some server. That server is running a Web app, implemented by somebody. Talk to that developer and ask that developer how the server is expecting the data to be formatted. *Then*, worry about how to get your data into that format.